# Laravel: Check if user is logged in before Laravel bootstrapping

Tags: php, laravel, session-cookies

I like to check via vanilla PHP, before **Laravel 6.x** is bootstrapped, if a user is logged in. I've tried it by using the application session cookie, but I dont know how to verify this token as valid user session token without the use of Laravel. It seems like the session token is not stored in the database.

This is a  example session token which is set by the responding HTTP-Requests:

```
Set-Cookie: my_app_session=eyJpdiI6ImxQMjlzY2NpcTJGQ3ZJRGtMSlBiOEE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiRms5WURpa05IM2ZiQmRlNFpDSVRlNGd5aEFBczVnMERSQ1dGNmREMEt1ZGJoS2hYRXlwYnQrSmxrMUJVWk9PMiIsIm1hYyI6IjYwYjFlYWFhNzIxNmQ0MWQ2N2FlNzAyN2ZmOWM4ZWUxZmUzYmE1ZWQ2ZWYzYzNmNzdhMTc5MWJiYzIyNzkwOGQifQ%3D%3D; expires=Mon, 13-Jul-2020 13:56:44 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/; httponly
```

It would be nice if someone could guide how to verify the session without the use of Laravel or give me a different approach to check if a user is logged in before Laravel is available (vanilla PHP).

We want to check if a user is logged in before laravel is bootstrapped to add a specific logic to this case. We are using this lib https://github.com/linslin/laravel-coffee-cache and we dont want to send the cached file on cached routes if a user is logged in.

Comment: you would probably still need a big chunk of code, but what you can do is save the Laravel session to Redis, then use vanilla PHP to get the session key from the cookie and look it up in Redis

Comment: Can you give a little more information about why you want to do this.

Comment: why you want to do this, and laravel give you that out of the box ?! give us reasons to help you

Comment: @Rwd we want to check if a user is logged in before laravel is bootstrapped to add a specific logic to this case. We are using this lib https://github.com/linslin/laravel-coffee-cache and we dont want to send the cached file on cached routes if a user is logged in.